# how to input mulltiple post in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

here I have a database called temporary, in this table it contains the input value

[image]

in the column * jumlah out * I filled in each value, for example in the first row I entered the value 3 and the second row 5. But when I posted to the database, an error occurred, here I attach the results of the input vardump.

```
Array
(
    [id_outbound_voice] => 34
    [id_tf] => 2
    [petugas] => Bekasi
    [qty_outbound] => Array // is jumlah out
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

    [tgl_outbound] => 2020-09-15 06:50:30
)
1

Array
(
    [id_outbound_voice] => 34
    [id_tf] => 2
    [petugas] => Bekasi
    [qty_outbound] => Array // is jumlah out
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

    [tgl_outbound] => 2020-09-15 06:50:30
)
1
```

and I want it like this

```
 Array
    (
        [id_outbound_voice] => 34
        [id_tf] => 2
        [petugas] => Bekasi
        [qty_outbound] => 3 // is jumlah out
        [tgl_outbound] => 2020-09-15 06:50:30
    )
    1
    
    Array
    (
        [id_outbound_voice] => 34
        [id_tf] => 2
        [petugas] => Bekasi
        [qty_outbound] => 5  // is jumlah out
        [tgl_outbound] => 2020-09-15 06:50:30
    )
    1
```

my code

```
<tbody id="tbody">
<?php $no = 1;
foreach ($datas as $val) { ?>
<tr class="deleted">
    <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo $val->kd_barang ?>" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo $val->nama_barang ?>" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty_outbound[]" value="<?php echo $val->qty_outbound ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo $val->tgl_outbound ?>" readonly></td>
</tr>
<?php $no++;
} ?>
</tbody>

$tmp = $this->get_temporary($this->session->userdata('ses_id')); // table temporary
    foreach ($tmp as $val) {

      $data = array(
        'id_outbound_voice' => $last_key,
        'id_tf'             => $val->id_tf,
        'id_barang'         => $val->id_barang,
        'id_rak'            => $val->id_rak,
        'ekspedisi'         => $val->ekspedisi,
        'resi'              => $val->resi,
        'qty_outbound'      => $_POST['qty_outbound'], // is jumlah out
        'tgl_outbound'      => $val->tgl_outbound,
        'tgl_tf'            => $val->tgl_tf,=
      );
      echo "<pre>", print_r($data);
```

Comment: Hoping you want to edit a list of records from temporary table. If so, send primary key and all updated fields from front end itself. As I can see there are two records with all same fields except `No` and `Jumlah_out`. So when updating values you should atleast get `No`(if primary key) to identify which records to update. If I'm missing something, please elaborate your requirement, so we an have an idea.

Comment: is your temporary table `$tmp` have same data with the your `$datas`?

Comment: yes same ..............